# WSO2 IOTS: HTTP Status 500 - Cannot call method "getUIPermissions" of undefined

Tags: wso2, iot

when I trying to start `WSO2 IoTs Server` and go to `https://localhost:9443/devicemgt`, I'm getting the `error`

> HTTP Status 500 - Cannot call method getUIPermissions of undefined.

I'm using MySQL and run `WSO2 IoTs` alone on `localhost`.

[Carbon Logs here](http://pastebin.com/FuThFcNS)

Answer (score 0):

This issue is raised when you try to start the pack with a -Dsetup. You can execute the database scripts that are available in the dbscripts folder manually and then run the product. This issue has been fixed after the alpha release.